# separating url's domain and top level domain without parseurl

Tags: python

I have a URL and I want to separate the domain and top-level domain, however, I want to keep the period.
example
google.com > "google", ".com"
I've tried split(".") and hard code a "." but I don't want to hard code it.
without parseurl

Comment: You should use proper domain parsing functions to do so. At least `urllib.parse`

Answer (score 0):

By using capture groups in regex, you can do

```py
re.split('(\.)', 'google.com')
```

To get `['google', '.', 'com']`.

Comment: @Steve I think OP means hard coding the '.' after the splitting.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (maybe too simple) would be to,

```
url = "google.com"
delimiter = '.'

delimiter_idx = url.find(delimiter)
print(url[0:delimiter_idx]) # google
print(url[delimiter_idx:])  # .com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what you want with the usual URL, not just the domain, which is I think what you were asking for:

```
def extract_domain_parts(url):
    exp = re.compile(r"^([^/]*/+)?(.*)(\.[^\.]*?)(/|:|$)")

    m = exp.match(url)
    if m:
        tld = m.group(2)
        rest = m.group(3)
        return tld, rest

    return url, None # malformed url

tld, rest = extract_domain_parts('https://google.com:8888/a/b/c')
print("TLD: " + tld)
print("Rest: " + rest)
```

Result:

```
TLD: .com
Rest: google
```

This does also work for the case of starting with just the full domain name:

```
tld, rest = extract_domain_parts('google.com')
```

gives the same result.

If you do just want to separate off the TLD from an arbitrary domain name, then @liorr has it almost right.  But his solution only works for domains with one '.' in them.  `find` should be replaced with `rfind`:

```
url = "www.google.com"
delimiter = '.'

delimiter_idx = url.rfind(delimiter)
print(url[0:delimiter_idx]) # google
print(url[delimiter_idx:])  # .com
```

Result:

```
www.google
.com
```